# How do I write a powershell script that can be invoked to process one file as well as multiple files

Tags: powershell

I have created a powershell script that has a Foreach-Object loop that formats xml files located in InputFolder. (Format-XML is a function)

```
Get-ChildItem C:\InputFolder -Filter *.xml | 
Foreach-Object {
        cat $_.FullName | Format-XML    
}
```

Now we are in a different phase of the project where we don't wish to run it for all the files but just the one new file which comes in.

How do I create a powershell script which can take one file name as input and at other times be invoked in such a way that it can also process multiple files if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a parameter for the script, so that you can specify what you want it to process. Something like:

```
Param(
    $Path
)
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter *.xml | 
Foreach-Object {
        cat $_.FullName | Format-XML    
}
```

Then you can call the script like:

```
.\FormatXMLFiles.ps1 'C:\InputFolder'
```

which would process the entire folder, or

```
.\FormatXMLFiles.ps1 'C:\InputFolder\MyFile.xml'
```

which would only do that one file.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ValueFromPipeline` property on the `Parameter` attribute for your function argument.

Example:

```
function foo
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param( [Parameter( Mandatory = $true,
                       Position = 0,
                       ValueFromPipeline = $true )]
           [string] $File
         )

    process
    {
        Write-Host "The file is: $File"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PS C:\Users\me> 'a', 'b' | foo
The file is: a
The file is: b

PS C:\Users\me> foo -File 'a'
The file is: a
```

Comment: That's great for a function, but less so for a script. Even better IMO is to add the `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true` property to the parameter, and add `[alias('FullName')]` to it, and you can just pipe `Get-ChildItem` to the function.